# Gnuplot, Multiplot Overlapping legend entries

Tags: gnuplot, legend

I am trying to plot the graph of the inverse function to y=xe^x, where the plot above y=-1 is a solid line, and below is a dashed line. I would like to label the solid and dashed lines separately, but they appear on top of each other. How can I get around this?

Here is my code:

```
set multiplot
set parametric
set style arrow 1 head filled size char 1.5,20,50 

set arrow 1 from -4.1,0 to 4.1,0 heads  
set arrow 2 from 0,-4.1 to 0,4.1 heads

set trange[-4:4]
set xrange[-4:4]
set yrange[-4:4]

set xlabel "x"
set ylabel "y"

unset border

set xtics axis format " "
set ytics axis format " "

set arrow from -exp(-1),-1 to -exp(-1),0 nohead lt 3
set arrow from -exp(-1),-1 to 0,-1 nohead lt 3

set label "$e^{-1}" at -exp(-1),0.2
set label "-1" at 0.1,-1
plot [-1:4] t*exp(t),t title '$W_{0}(x)'$ lt rgb "black"   
plot[-4:-1]  t*exp(t),t  lt 3  title '$W_{-1}(x)$'
```

which produces this figure:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dylom.jpg

Answer (score 2):

They appear on top of each other because you're plotting twice (i.e. you're using the `plot` command twice). Try the following conditional plot:

```
plot [-4:4] t*exp(t),(t < -1 ? t : 1/0) title '$W_{0}(x)$' lt rgb "black", \
t*exp(t),(t > -1 ? t : 1/0)  lt 3  title '$W_{-1}(x)$'
```

You don't need `multiplot` with the above.